# Minecraft Skin has weird patches and pixels on the hands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

My Minecraft Skin has these really wierd pixels on the hands. It is attatched and so is a screenshot of the pixels. I am on Java Edition macOS. It happens on 1.8.9 and 1.16.5.[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the two groups of 6 and 5 pixels and the group of 6 black with 3 white pixels, all arranged in lines?

Comment: It would be nice if you had a second picture with a close up, as two other users miss-understood the problem. Could you also tell me: Does the problem persist when you turn of your outter layer of the skin? And are you using any kind of anti-aliasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is perfectly normal.

The "weird" pixels are part of your skin itself. If we zoom into your skin...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlIgl.png]

We can see that it is shaded with some noise.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with them. That is how Minecraft is supposed to look.
Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: Hi Soumil30, can you provide some examples of this? If you got a high-res screenshot *directly* from Minecraft (i.e., an official screenshot), that would really add weight to your answer.

Comment: Ok I added a picture I took myself @Fato39.